# Openweathermap get icons by sunrise / sunset or day / night

Tags: jquery, json, openweathermap

I have a little function:

```
function weather(){
$.getJSON("http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast/city?id=6551933&units=metric&lang=de&APPID=4649XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX5b96",function(result){
    $("#header .inside").append("<div id='weather'><div class='temp' style='background-image:url(/files/images/weather/" + result.list[0].weather[0].icon + ".png);'>" + Math.round(result.list[0].main.temp) + "°</div><div class='wind'>" + Math.round(result.list[0].wind.speed * 3.6) + "km/h</div></div>");
    console.log("Weathericon: " + result.list[0].weather[0].icon);
    console.log("Temperature: " + result.list[0].main.temp);
    console.log("Wind: " + (result.list[0].wind.speed * 3.6) + " km/h");
});
}
```

This works perfectly. Just one thing: When it's 4pm the iconset goes to nighttime. Which should happen on sunset. And change again on sunrise.

Anyone with ideas? :) Thanks!

Comment: Have you checked that the city ID is correct? Maybe the given time is local that's why you have a lag.

Comment: Yes, I'm sure that id 6551933 is Waabs, Germany.
Is there any way for me to change the icon result? Like a parameter or something?

Comment: I don't know this API but you should have a look at `sys`: `sys.sunrise` and `sys.sunset` in your JSON response. Might be a lead.